# Is it safe to use an IDE to SATA power adapter for an extended period of time?

Tags: power-supply, sata, adapter, pata

I just bought a computer from HP and they failed to include SATA power connectors with the power supply other then the one HD and DVD drive. Meanwhile I have two IDE to SATA power adapters that came with my "USB 2.0 to SATA/IDE cable" [http://www.amazon.com/USB-2-0-SATA-Cable-Adapter/dp/B001OORN06](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OORN06) 3rd pic on the left.

I was wondering if I would just open up my computer and use it to plug it my SATA drives to the IDE power sources and mount it to the motherboard, would it damage my drives in the long run or have any other significant effects. A friend told me he knows people who have had their HD burn out because of this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My experience: I administer a small compute rcenter with 30 computers, each with two hard drives and two dvd-rom drives. The HDDs are SATA and they use the converters. It's been 2 years now and not a single drive has failed and neither have the PSUs. They are safe because they are designed to draw more or less the same amount of power as IDE drives.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is safe as long you always keep the cable connection good. Don't forget to always safely remove the drive before you pull out the hard drive.

My WD Blue 1 TB 3.5 inch is broken. I can recover the data but I can't re-format it, now its an unknown partition (maybe I'll take it to WD for service soon). It was caused by the power cable from the PSU, which was torn so the HDD stop immediately.

I use the IDE to SATA cable to connect it to my laptop (I think it not safe for long period cause I shut down the PSU manually, but I think it is safe for PCs).